# Will voluntary fasts compensate any shortage in obligatory fasts on the Day of Judgement?

Tags: sawm, day-of-judgement, fard, nafl

If I had fallen short of my obligatory fasts without being aware, will my voluntary fasts be counted to compensate them on the Day of Judgement like the way shortage in obligatory Salah is compensated with voluntary Salah?